# Need help with combinatiorics (apparently).

Tags: combinatorics

I asked a question on stack overflow for help with an equation I need for my program. They however thought my question was a more mathematical one, and suggested I should go here instead, so I will copy/paste my question here below. I also learned it has to do with "combinatiorics", but reading about it didn't help me so much (Yes, I'm really not a mathematician; not even sure what to search for):

"Let's see if I can put this right:

I have "x" amount of "ingredients" that I want to mix.

There can only be mixed a total of "y" ingredients together. (Meaning if y=3, I can only make a salad with MAXIMUM three ingredients (Less ingredients is ok.), even if I have more ingredients available.)

Ok, here's my problem; I want to know how many UNIQUE dishes that can possibly be made out of the amount of ingredients (x), when y=whatever.

Lets call the ingredients A,B,C,D... etc.

So, again if y=3 and x=4 (A,B,C,D), unique dishes would e.g be:

A,
AD,
ABB,
DBA,
etc...
However, the dishes DBA and ADB, for example, would consist of the same amount of equal ingredients and basically be the same dish, and therefore only be counted ONE time."

Hope I could explain myself somewhat correct.

Thanks!

EDIT: As pointed out, x is the amount of different ingredients, but there's an infinite number of each of them. Meaning in the above example, that a dish could also be e.g.: AA, ABB, CCC.

Comment: Are you allowing the *same* ingredient to be used twice in the same dish? E.g., you give ABB as a dish.

Comment: Yes, that's allowed! I was just correcting this in a below comment. I will put an edit in the question.

Comment: I suspect the question "how many distinct dishes exist with *exactly* $y$ ingredients (counting duplicates)" will be easier; the answer to your question is then the sum of the answer to this new question.

Comment: A bit more delicate put, yes! Still don't know how to crack it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you need here is "combinations with repetition", rather than just combinations. You can think of a combination-with-repetition of $k$ elements from a selection of $n$ choices by putting the choices and the combination in order; that is, by asserting a canonical order on the different ingredients, and then imposing the restriction that any dish must have its ingredients listed in order.

Now, the distinction between two dishes of the same size is exactly where in the recipe you move from one ingredient to the next. That is, a recipe for a dish of size $k$ consists of the statement "Add whatever you're holding" exactly $k$ times, and "Move to the next ingredient" exactly $n-1$ times (because you have to get from the first ingredient to the last). Therefore, there are exactly ${(n - 1) + k \choose k}$ legal recipes of size $k$ (because you have to choose $k$ steps out of the $n - 1 + k$ to be "add stuff"), and the total number of dishes up to size $k$ is just $$ \sum_{i=1}^k {n + i - 1 \choose i} = \sum_{i=1}^k {n + i - 1 \choose n - 1}. $$

Lucky for you, there is a simple closed form for this summation! The second form is very close to the "hockey-stick identity" (look it up), and a simple inductive proof gives its closed form as ${n + k \choose n} - 1$. (The $-1$ represents the "empty dish", the unique dish with 0 ingredients for any $n$.) This last expression can be thought of as adding one more "move to the next ingredient" step to our recipe, with the understanding that moving past the last ingredient in the list means to stop cooking; equivalently, it's the number of unique dishes with exactly $k$ ingredients chosen from $n+1$ ingredients, where the extra added ingredient is the "empty ingredient" that makes up the difference for smaller dishes.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I really wish I understood a bit of what you just explained to me.. Although trying my hardest, I feel I miss some basic knowledge to these kind of explanations. However, is what you have been drawing up, by any chance, the same as this?: ((n+k-1)!/(n-1)!)/k! It seems to work when I test it.

Comment: @user3412636 Your expression is the definition of ${n + k - 1 \choose k}$; so this is the number of dishes with exactly $k$ ingredients chosen from $n$ ingredients (allowing repetition). My explanation was just meant to show how to get that expression.

Answer (score 1):

The number of unique ways to pick $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements is $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, in your case you need $\sum\limits_{i=1}^y \binom{x}{i}$.

For example let y=3 and x=4 (A,B,C,D), the number of possible dishes is:

$\binom{4}{1}=4$ there are 4 dishes with one ingredient, namely A,B,C and D)

$\binom{4}{2}=6$ there are 6 dishes with two ingredients, namely AB,AC,AD,BC,BD and CD

$\binom{4}{3}=4$ there are 4 dishes with three ingredients, namely ABC,ABD,BCD and ACD

so there are $4+6+4=14$ unique dishes

Comment: Just to add to this solution, if you can allow upto $x$ possible ingredients, then the sum becomes $\sum_{i=1}^{x}\binom{x}{i}$ which has a closed form solution equal to $2^x - 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is almost what I'm looking for. My fault, I explained it a bit wrong. What I wanted is that; X is the amount of different ingredients, but there's endless of each of these ingredients. So a dish could also be e.g. AA, ABB, CDD. I'll make an edit in the question. Thanks again!

Comment: use combination with repetition then, which is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ instead of $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: @Alessandro: Combinations with repetition should be $n + k - 1 \choose k$; what you suggested is permutations.

Comment: @PaulZ: you're right, thanks for the correction!